# jQuery UI Button for Select Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, button

on jQuery UI you can transform checkboxes or radio fields to buttons -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Now I want the same for the option values of select fields.
That means:

```
<select name="text">
 <option>Value 1</option>
 <option>Value 2</option>
 <option>Value 3</option>
 <option>Value 4</option>
</select>
```

Should be transformed to:

```
<input type="button" value="Value 1">
<input type="button" value="Value 2">
<input type="button" value="Value 3">
<input type="button" value="Value 4">
```

Does have anyone a solutions for my matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
var buttons = "";
$("select option").each(function () {
    buttons += "<input type='button' value='" + this.value + "'/>";    
});

$("select").replaceWith(buttons);​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/mBUgc/1)